# how to invoke script Powershell to my backend .net core?

Tags: .net, azure, powershell, asp.net-core, azure-vm

How to invoke a script PowerShell in backend .netcore ? for example when I clicked at but I run a script PowerShell for build VM to azure via a template?

I need a Solution for that workshop.

Thanks.

.net

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions supports Powershell. All you have to do is call the Azure Functions endpoint, which will execute the code to build the VM.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal